# Passing 2D arrays to function

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make an ASCII world, however I am unable to pass 2D arrays between functions. It is a 20 x 20 array, and I want to place houses randomly across it. The array won't pass like I want it to, and my tutorial told me that global variables are evil, so a solution without those would be great.

```
using namespace std;

void place_house(const int width, const int height, string world[width][length])
{
    int max_house    = (width * height) / 10; //One tenth of the map is filled with houses
    int xcoords = (0 + (rand() % 20));
    int ycoords = (0 + (rand() % 20));
    world[xcoords][ycoords] = "@";
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    const int width  = 20;
    const int height = 20;
    string world[width][height];
    string grass    = ".";
    string house    = "@";
    string mountain = "^";
    string person   = "Å";
    string treasure = "$";
    //Fill entire world with grass
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 20; ++iii) {
        for (int jjj = 0; jjj < 20; ++jjj) {
            world[iii][jjj] = ".";
        }
    }
    place_house(width, height, world);
    for (int iii = 0; iii < 20; ++iii) {
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < 20; ++jjj) {
        cout << world[iii][jjj] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: If each string in your array contains exactly one character, you should probably use a two-dimensional array of `char`, not a two-dimensional array of `string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `string **` instead of `string[][]`

So your function should be declared like this:

```
void place_house(const int width, const int height, string **world)
```

and then you access your array usual way.

Remember to handle bounds correctly (probably you want to pass them together with array).

---

edit:

This is how you might achieve what you need:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo (string **bar)
{
    cout << bar[0][0];
}

int main(void)
{
    string **a = new string*[5];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ )
        a[i] = new string[5];

    a[0][0] = "test";

    foo(a);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++ )
        delete [] a[i];
    delete [] a;
    return 0;
}
```

---

edit

Another way of achieving what you want achieve (that is passing static array to a function) is to pass it as one dimmensional array and then use C-like way of accessing it.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo (string *bar)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
        {
            cout << bar[ (r * 5) + c ] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    string a[5][5];
    a[1][1] = "test";
    foo((string*)(a));
    return 0;
}
```

This little example is nicely described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/49079/) (see Duoas post).

So I hope this will describe different ways of doing similar thing. This, however, does look quite ugly and probably is not the best programming practice (I would do everything to avoid doing that this way, dynamic arrays are quite nice you just need to remember releasing them).

Comment: Thanks! But now it says that there is no matching function for this: place_house(width, height, world);

Comment: This does not work because the argument being passed is a two-dimensional array, but this changes the parameter to be a pointer to a pointer, and a two-dimesional array cannot be converted to a pointer to a pointer. One could change the array, but that requires additional allocations and assignments of pointers and is wasteful and a nuisance.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Then how can I make it work without any problems?

Comment: @Lemonizer: As long as your array has fixed dimensions, see [the answer by “soon”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16320242/298225). If your dimensions may vary at run time, other techniques are needed.

Comment: @Greg0ry: That cast converts a pointer to an array of `height` `string` to a pointer to a pointer to `string`. When the parameter is dereferenced once, the type is pointer to `string`, but the value is an address of an array of string. There is no pointer there, so dereferencing it a second time produces garbage.

Comment: @Lemonizer: This could not have worked. You must have changed something else in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Since your array has compile-time known dimensions, you could use templates to detect it like this:

```
template <std::size_t W, std::size_t H>
void place_house(string (&world)[W][H])
{
    int max_house    = (W * H) / 10; //One tenth of the map is filled with houses
    int xcoords = (0 + (rand() % 20));
    int ycoords = (0 + (rand() % 20));
    world[xcoords][ycoords] = "@";
}

// ...

place_house(world); // Just pass it
```

Note, that this trick **will not works with dynamically allocated arrays**. In that case, you should use something like `std::vector`.

Comment: I was always having some feeling (which is probably wrong), that doing things C++ way produces beautiful code but when it comes to robustness C-like solutions are much faster...

Comment: @Greg0ry, _"much"_? Don't think so. Also, I have a rule: _"Do not ever mix C and C++."_

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to size the parameter in the declaration and can't because the [][] syntax requires compile time constants.

Replace with string world[][] and it should work.

If it doesn't then use string[]* world  (an array of array of strings is actually an array of pointers to an array of string)

I hope this helps, my C++ is becoming increasingly rusty.

Comment: Like this?
void place_house(const int width, const int height, string world[][])

And call using this
place_house(width, height, world)

This doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Not compiling or not executing well?